# Can't update hidden checkbox name attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am having trouble updating the name attribute of **funding_status[0]** in my cloned hidden checkbox input with class name of **funding_status_hidden**.  I can update the normal input with class funding_status with the following js script. It also updates a bunch of other checkbox fields as intended - struggling to get this last one to change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var template = $('#products .product:first').clone();
var productsCount = $('.product').length-1; 

window.addProduct = function(){
    productsCount++;
    var product = template.clone().find(':input, .days').val('0').prop('checked', false).each(function(){

        var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + productsCount;

        $(this).next(':input, label').attr('for', newId); // update label for
        $(this).next(".funding_status").attr('name', function() { return $(this).attr("name").substring(0, this.id.length-2) + "["+productsCount+"]" });
        $(this).next(".funding_status_hidden").attr('name', function() { return $(this).attr("name").substring(0, this.id.length-2) + "["+productsCount+"]" });


        this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)



        $(this).find(".cloned_checkbox_hidden").attr("name", function() { return $(this).attr("name").substring(0, this.id.length-9) + "["+productsCount+"]" });
        $(this).find(".cloned_checkbox").attr("name", function() { return $(this).val('1').attr("name").substring(0, this.id.length-2) + "["+productsCount+"]" });




    }).end()
    .attr('id', 'product' + productsCount)
    .appendTo('#products');

}
$('.add').click(addProduct);
$("a#rp").click(function () {
    productsCount--;
if ($(".product").length != 1) {
$(".product:last").remove();
}
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

**HTML of cloned Div (cut down a bit to show the funding section I am trying to update)**

```
<div id="product2" class="product m-b-20">
<div class="field is-horizontal">
    <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-body">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <label for="is-gov-funded" class="label">Funding</label> 
                            <div class="select is-fullwidth m-b-15">
                                    <select id="gov_fundin2" name="gov_funding[]" class="input funding_dropdown">
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="III">III</option>
                                        <option value="HC">HC</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                    <div class="column">
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <label class="label">Funding Amount</label> 
                                    <input type="number" step="0.01" name="funding_amount[]" value="" class="input funding_amount" id="2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <label class="label has-text-white m-b-20">Funding Status</label> 
                                <input id="funding_status_hidden_2" name="funding_status[0]" type="hidden" value="0" class="is-checkradio is-link funding_status_hidden"> 
                                <input id="funding_status_2" name="funding_status[0]" type="checkbox" value="0" class="is-checkradio f_input funding_status is-link" for="gov_funding_status_hidden_2"> 
                                <label for="funding_status_2" class="label">Approved</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working demo/snippet or maybe a [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) to work with please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
document.getElementById("input-id").name ="new name";
```

for change name

and dont use [0] in name

use data-name like this

```
<input data-name="array[0]" >
```

for class

```
var t = document.getElementById("cloned-data-container");

t.querySelector(".your-spacial-input-classname").name = "custom value";
```

Comment: The Id is generated during the .clone and a number is appended to the id so in this case _2 so a bit hard for me to get the id, is class possible?

Comment: use classname and get relative inputs with classname

Comment: Can I do something like `var t = document.getElementById("product" + productsCount")` to select the cloned-data-container?

Comment: yeah ("product" + productsCount)

Comment: I ended up using `var t = document.getElementById("funding_status_hidden_" + productsCount).name = "funding_status" + "["+productsCount+"]";` to get what I needed.  Thanks for putting me on the right track hossein!

Comment: It is my pleasure